# identifier of an instance of ...was altered from

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

i found many response about this title "identifier of an instance of ...was altered from ..." but none of this give me a solution.

i am using PostgreSQL
with just 2 column id_type and libelle.

here is my Model level :

```
package com.stev.pillecons.pilleCons.models;   

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name = "type_pille")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler"})
public class LePille {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id_type;
    private String libelle;
    public  LePille(){}
    public String getLibelle() {
        return libelle;
    }
    public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
        this.libelle = libelle;
    }
    public int getId_type() {
        return id_type;
    }
    public void setId_type(int id_type) {
        this.id_type = id_type;
    }
}
```

My Service level :

```
@Override
public LePille updatePille(Integer id, LePille  Sourcepille) {
    Optional<LePille> existingSession = pilleRepo.findById(id);

    if (existingSession.isPresent())
    {
        LePille  Targetpile = existingSession.get();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(Sourcepille, Targetpile);
        return pilleRepo.saveAndFlush(Targetpile);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new PilleException("pille not found");
    }
}
```

when i debug it, with the data

> {"id_type":10,"libelle":"dsf"}

with postman [image]

the value of TargetPille is : {"id_type":10,"libelle":"dsf"}
and the value of SourcePille : {"id_type":0,"libelle":"popo"}

last but not least is Controller level:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity update(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody LePille session) {
      LePille updPille =   pilleService.updatePille(id, session);
        return new ResponseEntity<LePille>(updPille, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

it is strange because juste update that not working, Create, Read and Delete works fine.

thanks in advance

Comment: You should be updating the `source` not the `target` and you shouldn't copy the `id`. That being said, using `BeanUtils` shouldnb't be a best practice (as the documentation states it is mainly for internal framework use). That being said, unrelated, an `if` with an optional, is considered bad practice. You should be using `map` and `orElseThrow` and chain those together.

Answer (score 0):

i just change the code like this:

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(Sourcepille, Targetpile, "id_type");
```

just add the id_type to ignore variable